# SSL - Insecure connection

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate

I am using a self-signed certificate from OpenSSL on localhost with the URL https://localhost.com:3000
Chrome is complaining about an insecure connection. Your connection to this site is not secure
This is my openssl.conf

```
[req]
default_bits = 2048
distinguished_name = dn
prompt             = no

[dn]
C="US"
ST="CA"
L="Venice Beach"
O="YIDAS"
OU="Service"
emailAddress="myemail@gmail.com"
CN="localhost.com"

[req_ext]
subjectAltName = DNS:127.0.0.1

[alt_names]
DNS.1=localhost.com 
DNS.2=$HOSTNAME 
IP.1=127.0.0.1
[v3_req]
keyUsage = critical, digitalSignature, keyAgreement
extendedKeyUsage = serverAuth
subjectAltName = DNS:127.0.0.1
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Need way more information. Chrome gives more information in the error message.

First, try using the address *localhost* and use it both in the CN and subjectAltName fields. An ip address is not a DNS name.

Second, verify that whatever server is using the created certificate by inspecting it from chrome.

Third, make sure the certificate is trusted by chrome by importing it into the chrome certificate store.

Comment: This what Chrome tells me:
This page is not secure (broken HTTPS).
Certificate - missing
This site is missing a valid, trusted certificate (net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID).
View certificate
Connection - secure connection settings
The connection to this site is encrypted and authenticated using TLS 1.3, X25519, and AES_128_GCM.
Resources - all served securely
All resources on this page are served securely.

Comment: soorry for the late respoonse - net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID means you haven't trusted the certificate in chrome